Is the constraint $f(A) = \sqrt{x^T A x} \le t$ convex
I know that second order cone constraint $ f(x) = \sqrt{x^TAx}\le t $ is convex set given matrix $A$ semi-definite (If I am wrong, please point it out.)
I wonder if the variable changes from vextor $x$ to matrix $A$, will the resulting constraint $ f(A) = \sqrt{x^TAx}\le t $ be convex set?
In addition, $t$ is a constant, and $A$ is semi-definite constrained.

and you also have a constraint that $A$ is semi positive definite?

It would just be a half space. (I am assuming that $t$ is a constant.)

@Yimin Yes, $t$ is a constant and $A$ is semi-definite. The half space means it is a convex set, right?

If $x$ is fixed, the the constraint can be written as $x^TAx \le t^2$.
If $$x^TA_1x \le t^2$$ and
$$x^TA_2x \le t^2$$
then $x^T(\alpha A_1 + (1-\alpha)A_2)x=\alpha x^TA_1x + (1-\alpha)x^TA_2x\le t^2$
